# how to make auto completer work with Jquery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, post, autocomplete

I am trying to use autocomplete, ajax call work perfectly when I use out side the auto completor. But Following code doesnt work. How to set data to source properly?

```
$("#searchbox").autocomplete({ source: [{

        var search_val = $("#searchbox").val();
    $.ajax( {
        type : "POST",
        url : "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data : {
            action : 'wpay_search',
            user_name : search_val
        },
        success : function(data) {
        //$('#search_result').html(data);
        return data;

        }
    });

}] });
```

Comment: What exactly does "doesnt work" mean? What errors do you get?

Comment: noting is load #searchbox and javascript is freezed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an easier way would be to pass in a callback function as the source, which would be more flexible and suited for what you are trying to accomplish.  According to the jQuery UI documentation:

The callback gets two arguments:

- A request object, with a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo".
- A response callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

Looking at your code, it might be something like:

```
$("#searchbox").autocomplete({ 
       //define the callback function
       source: function(request, response) {
                   $.ajax({
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                        data: request,
                        success: function(data) {
                                   //create array for response objects  
                                   var acTerms = [];  

                                   //process response and add it to the array  
                                   $.each(data,function(i,val){                                
                                        acTerms.push(val.username);  //whatever your username property is
                                   });  

                                   //pass array to response callback  
                                   response(acTerms); 
                    });
        });
 });
```

Your PHP script would use the "term" property on the request object sent as the data in order to retrieve the appropriate results and echo the resulting JSON, where it is handled by the success callback.

There is a good tutorial on using the function callback as the source at [How to use the jQuery UI Autocomplete Widget](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/).

**Update:**

I went back and realized that an easier method to handle your AJAX request would be to pass in a string to the source callback pointing to the URL of your script.

jQuery UI documentation states:

- When a string is used [as the source type], the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is set to "http://example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request would be made to http://example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

Your code would then be changed to:

```
$("#searchbox").autocomplete({ 
       //define the callback function
       source: "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
 });
```

You will have to handle the term passed in with the GET request ($_GET["term"]) in your PHP script. Since your script returns a string encoded in JSON format, assuming that your JSON is properly formatted, your autocomplete feature should populate correctly.

Comment: why didnt you directly pass response(data) ? I get data as string encoded to jason format, which contain only usernames.

Comment: Can you give me a sample of your json that is returned? If your json returned looks like { user1: bob, user2: joe, ...}, then make sure that you create an array like [ { user1: bob, user2: joe, ...} ] before passing it into the response callback, because you can't directly give a string to the response callback unless it is a URL pointing to a resource returning JSON.

Comment: How ever, I can't passe variable to request.

Comment: Isn't the variable you are trying to pass the user-typed value? In your code above, you have the value of the search box, meaning the text that the user enters.  This is sent in a GET request, which can be accessed in your PHP script as $_GET["term"] and used for filtering.